# Java Test Automation - Test Case Annotation to Extent report

Tags: java, annotations, extentreports

I created a new annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface DisplayName {
    String value() ; 
}
```

That I wanted to use in order to define the test case name in extent report. On test case:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("testcase title")
public void TestCase_1() throws InterruptedException {...}
```

In The TestListener I now managed to set the title of the test case using the description field.

```
    @Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    System.out.println("I am in onTestStart method " + getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + " start");
    // Start operation for extentreports.
    ExtentTestManager.startTest(iTestResult.getMethod().getDescription(), iTestResult.getMethod().getDescription());
}
```

I would like to use the @DisplayName annotation as test case title but I don't know how to bring the annotation value in TestListener.

Thanks in advance!

SOLUTION__________________With great help from @Kovacic__________________SOLUTION

Final Result:

Annotation class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface DisplayName {
    String value();
}
```

TestListener Class:

```
........
@Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult iTestResult) {

        String valueFromInterface = null;

        Method method = iTestResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();

        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(DisplayName.class)) {
            DisplayName displayName = method.getAnnotation(DisplayName.class);
            if (displayName != null) {
              valueFromInterface = displayName.value();
            }
        }

        ExtentTestManager.startTest(valueFromInterface, iTestResult.getMethod().getDescription());
    }

........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood this question, here is solution

if You use this as interface:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ITestrail {
    public @interface DisplayName {
        String value() ; 
    }
```

also You need to add to Your interface (line bellow):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

try this:

```
@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

    String valueFromInterface;

    Method method = result.getMethod().getMethod();

    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(DisplayName.class)) {
        DisplayName displayName = method.getAnnotation(DisplayName.class);
        if (displayName != null) {
          valueFromInterface = displayName.value();
        }
    }

    ExtentTestManager.startTest(iTestResult.getMethod().getDescription(), valueFromInterface);
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Method method = result.getMethod().getMethod();
should be 
Method method = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();

but i got valueFromInterface -   null, becouse i need to instantiate the variable and of course I have the annotation set on method @DisplayName("Test Title")

Comment: Is answer ok then?

Comment: Forgot to add @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME), try adding this to interface, and it should work

Comment: It is working YEY, I will update the solution thanks to you!

Comment: Glad I could help, it slipped my mind to add in answer c/p error.